# How do I add Python list in order?

Tags: python, list

I want to make a code that receives a random list and stores only positive numbers.
However, if I run it with the code I wrote, I only get positive numbers, but the order is reversed. What should I do?

As an example of the code, [3, 2, 1, 0] is displayed.
I want to print this out [0, 1, 2, 3].

```
def filter(list):
    flist = []
    for i in list:
        if list[i]>=0:
            flist.append(list[i])
        else:
            continue
    return flist
    
list = [-1,-2,-3,-4,0,1,2,3]
print(filter(list))
```

Comment: `i` is not a list index, it's a list element. `list[i]` is not the current element of the iteration.

Comment: Have you considered a list comprehension instead: `[x for x in list if x >= 0]`

Comment: when you do `for i in list` i is an element of list, not an index, so you shouldn't do `flist.append(list[i])`  but ` flist.append(i)` instead

Comment: So on the first iteration, you're appending `list[-1]`, which is the last element of the list.

Comment: Also, `list` is a class in module builtins - it is a poor name for a variable.

Comment: [[1]] Zero is not Positive [[2]] To get the "correct output" , try `append(i)` , not `append(list[i])` + update the `if` condition to use `i` , not `list[i]` (this is what @Barmar is Pointing out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for i in list` iterates over the items in the list, not the indices.  Since the first four items in the list are negative numbers, when you use them as indices, you end up iterating through the last half of the list in reverse order before reaching zero and then iterating through the first half of the list in forward order.  (If all the items in the list didn't happen to be valid indices for that same list, you'd just get an `IndexError` instead.)

To iterate over all the items in the list in order by index use `range` and `len`:

```
# 'filter' and 'list' are both builtin names, don't redefine them

def filter_nat(nums):
    flist = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[i]>=0:
            flist.append(nums[i])
        else:
            continue
    return flist
    
nums = [-1,-2,-3,-4,0,1,2,3]
print(filter_nat(nums))  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

It's simpler to iterate by value, though; you just need to use the value itself rather than trying to use it as an index:

```
def filter_nat(nums):
    flist = []
    for i in nums:
        if i >=0:
            flist.append(i)
    return flist
    
nums = [-1,-2,-3,-4,0,1,2,3]
print(filter_nat(nums))  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

and it's simpler yet to use a comprehension instead of individually `append`ing each item:

```
def filter_nat(nums):
    return [i for i in nums if i >= 0]
    
nums = [-1,-2,-3,-4,0,1,2,3]
print(filter_nat(nums))  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I found out what I missed and what was new.

Answer (score 0):

sort before returning the list

```
def filter(list):
        flist = []
        for i in list:
            if list[i]>=0:
                flist.append(list[i])
            else:
                continue
        flist.sort()
        return flist
    
list = [-1,-2,-3,-4,0,1,2,3]
print(filter(list))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: i is not an index, but an element of list, so you cannot do list[i]

Comment: I think he wants them to be in the same order as the original list, not sorted numerically.

Comment: I don't want to be sorted, I want it to be printed in the order of what's in the original list. I think I said something that could be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want? Something in the same order as encountered reading from left to right or in increasing order? If it is in the order of reading in initial list, here is the answer:

function append() adds the element at the end of the list. Hence, you could either go over the list from the end to its beginning using append() or going in same order as you, use another fashion in order to add the element at the beginning. When sticking to your code, we would have

```
def filter(list):
    flist = []
    for i in list:
        if list[i]>=0:
            flist = [i] + flist
        else:
            continue
    return flist
```

However, this could be written way more "pythonic" in the following way:

```
def filter(list):
   return [i for i in list if i>=0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for i in range (len(list)):

You would be looping through the number of items in the list. Personally it is easier and cleaner code for me but everyone has his preferences.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```py
print(filter(list[::-1]))
```

Comment: TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 1

Comment: check the definition of your filter function. modify accordingly.
the whole idea here was to iterate through the list in the reverse order using the shorthand
list[::-1] which would be the step for the index.

Comment: But you are doing the same mistake the OP did with this answer: believing that the problem is that the filter function returns list in reverse order. It was returning list indexed by the elements of the list; and unfortunately, the chosen example, whose first element where -1,-2,-3,-4, makes it appears as if that meant "list in reverse order", since `[list[-1], list[-2], list[-3], list[-4]]` are, by definition, the 4 last items of the list, in reverse order.